# How to get jquery updated values, from a select (ASP.NET Listbox)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox

I'm adding values, to a listbox, with jquery's Append. I simply write an option, in HTML, and append it, on a button click.

Now, once the page posts, I would like to store these values, in my database. However, it seems like the Listbox is empty. When I view source, it also appears empty. I guess I don't fully understand the client side concept.

How do I get these non-existing values, into my code-behind?

This is the add function:

```
function AddGPWNum() {
var TestNum = $("#<%= TestNumText.ClientID %>").val();
if (TestNum.length == 0)
    return false;
var NewString = TestNum.split("<");
NewString = NewString.join("&lt;");

$("#<%= TestNumText.ClientID %>").val("");
TestNum = '<option value="' + NewString + '">' + NewString + '</option>';
$("#<%= TestNumList.ClientID %>").append(TestNum);

$("#<%= HiddenNumbers.ClientID %>").val() = $("#<%= TestNumList.ClientID %> > option").map(function () { return this.value }).get().join(',');

return false;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net will only see the added values if they are chosen by the user as they are then returned as part of the `Request` collection.

If jQuery adds values to the listbox then you will not see them if you do a 'view source' on your page as they have been dynamicaly added to the DOM. You may ser them if you view the source with a tool like Firebug.

If you want to see the values you've added in the code-behind you could append the values you add to a hidden field as well as the listbox, the value of the hidden field would then be available in the code-behind and you could parse the values from that.

jQuery similar to this should write a comma seperated list of the listbox values into a hidden field -

```
$("#yourhiddenfieldid").val($("#yourlistboxid > option").map(function() {return this.value}).get().join(','));
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on how to do this. Can I grab all the values from the Listbox, and then write them into the hiddenfield, instead of only adding the one value, the user is writing in? If I don't overwrite the entire string, with all the options in the Listbox, how can I remove a single, specfic entry?

Comment: @Nicolai - I've added some jQuery to the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful, but I still don't quite get it. If I add your map command, to my add-button's function, it causes a postback. I assume it has to do with the return. My function returns false, in the end, to prevent postback. Can I keep the map command, in the Add-function, and prevent the postback? Or will I need to do the map when I save instead?

Comment: @Nicolai, the code I've posted shouldn't cause a postback. Could you add the code form your add button to the question?

Comment: Sorry - the code I posted had an error in it. I've updated the jQuery in the answer. Could you try again with the updated code?

Comment: Works like a charm :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field to store the values as you add it to the listbox. Then from code-behind you can get them to store it to the DB.